# Difference between array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION ) and $_SESSION['id];

Tags: php

in this code

```
if ((array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION) AND $_SESSION['id']) OR (array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE) AND $_COOKIE['id'])) {

    header("Location: loggedPage.php");

}
```

I dont know different between them. Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks

Minh Phuc

Comment: The first checks to make sure that the key exists. The second checks if the value is truthy (i.e. not 0, null, or false)

Comment: Do you wan't to know what the code does or do you want to know the difference between sessions and cookies?

Comment: Do you know that cookies can be manipulated on client side!? The first comment ist the answer to your question, this is an comment on you code.

Comment: `array_key_exists` will always return a boolean. The other returns the actual contents which will then be coerced to a boolean value (since it is being used in a boolean expression)

Comment: You could simply use `!empty($_SESSION['id'])`. It tests whether it exists and whether it's not an empty value in one step.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_key_exists(“id”, $_SESSION ) :
```

This lines checks whether id key exists in $_SESSION (Array) and returns true or false.

```
$_SESSION['id']) :
```

This lines returns the value of id in SESSION or returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

[`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) checks whether or not a key exists in an array, not caring what value the key might carry. It might carry false, null, 0 and so on..

`if($_SESSION['ID'])` returns the contents of the variable, after which it is cast as a **boolean**.

It is proven that [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is faster than `array_key_exists()`. The only difference between the two is `$key => null` will return **false** on `isset()` and **true** on `array_key_exists()`